# How do I correctly wrap Form Tags using CSS Flexbox

Tags: html, css, forms, flexbox, wrapper

I think it is my HTML which is formatted wrong, but I'm not sure. I am trying to center the form to start with using flexbox but nothing seems to be happening. Must I apply flex to each form section, that seems to defeat the purpose of using a flex wrapper in the first place? The input tags shouldn't need id selectors if they are wrapped within label tags surely?

My HTML Code:

```
<!--The HTML below is where I think the issue is, I started this project on myFreeCodeCamp and at the time they wanted me to have id selectors for both
the label and the input tags. I feel these selectors might be conflicting?-->
  
    <!--Flex Wrapper-->
  <div id="wrapper">

    <!--Form-->
    <form id='survey-form'>
      <!--Name Label-->
      <label id='name-label'>Name
        <input id='name' type="text" name='first-name' placeholder='Enter your name'required/>
      </label>
      <!--Email Label-->
      <label id='email-label'>Email <input id='email' type="email" name='email' placeholder='Enter your email' pattern='[a-z]{0-9}'required/></label>
      <!--Age Label-->
      <label id='number-label'>Age (optional) <input id='number' type='number' name='age' placeholder='Enter your age' pattern='{0-9}' min='16' max='120'/></label>
      
      <!--Dropdown Menu-->
      <p id="dropdown-title">  What is your favourite feature of freeCodeCamp?</p>
      <select id='dropdown'>
          <option>Select an option</option>
          <option>Projects</option>
          <option>Challenges</option>
          <option>Community</option>
          <option>Open Source</option>
      </select>
    </label>

      <!--Radio Button Menu-->
      <p id="radio-title">Would you recommend freeCodeCamp to a friend?</p>
      <label><input type='radio' name='radio' value='answer'> Definitely</label>
      <label><input type='radio' name='radio' value='answer'> Maybe</label>
      <label><input type='radio' name='radio' value='answer'> Not sure</label>
      
      <!--Checkbox Menu-->
      <label id="checkbox-title">What would you see improved? (Check all that apply)</label>
      <label><input type='checkbox' value='attribute'>Front-end projects</label>
      <label><input type='checkbox' value='attribute'>Back-end projects</label>
      <label><input type='checkbox' value='attribute'>Data Visualisation</label>
      <label><input type='checkbox' value='attribute'>Challenges</label>

      <label id="textarea-title">Any further comments or suggestions? <textarea placeholder='Additional comments'></textarea></label>

    <!--Submit Button-->
      <label id="submit-button"> <input id="submit" type='submit'></label>
  </div>
    </form>
  </div>
```

My CSS Code:

```
/*My attempt at using Flexbox to style a survey form*/
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box; 
    border: none;
    border-radius: 0.2em;
    
}

body {
    background-color: #383836;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

h1, h2 {
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 10px;
}


/*Flex Wrapper*/
 #wrapper {
    display: flex;
    background-color: darkgrey;
    max-width: 700px;
    height: 100vh;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
 }

/*Form ID Selector*/
 #survey-form {
    flex: 1;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: white;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 0.2em;
 }
```

Comment: you want to center the form and input one by one right?

Comment: add in your #survey-form ```display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap; flex-direction: column; align-items: center;```

Comment: This will be helpful for you https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/building-responsive-forms-with-flexbox--cms-26767

Comment: The form is a single column so the direction will be row. It must have something to do with the width of my containers maybe?